# Is it possible to add dynamic controls to a dockable window?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I am writing a small application that uses the dockable window. What will happen is that for each layer in the TOC a label and checkboxes will appear within the dockable window. However what do i need to do to add the control onto the Dock Window.
As an example i have

```
                IDataset dataset = enumDataset.Next();
            while (dataset != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dataset.Name);
                //create a label object 
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Name = "lbl_" + dataset.BrowseName;
                label.Text = dataset.Name;
                label.Top = top;
                label.Height = height;
```

But there is no

```
this.Controls.Add(label);
```

Does anyone know what the code should be to add the control?

Thanks

Comment: Silly mistake by me, I was in the wrong class file.